# Wireless network driver instillation.

Tags: wireless-networking

0

I have a laptop with a bad Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4 driver.

I have attempted to download a new driver on a laptop with a internet access, then transfer it with a USB.

The problem is that the driver needs to access the internet to complete the install, and the computer does not have internet access without the driver.

Any ideas on how I can install the Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4 driver without internet access?

Comment: Seems odd to me that the driver installation needs to access the internet. That's usually not the case. Can you [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1390760/edit) your post and include your laptop make and model number and also a link to where you downloaded the driver from. Also, are you not able to connect the laptop via ethernet cable directly to the wireless router in order to install the driver?

Comment: Seems odd to me too.  Perhaps the download contained unwanted items. The site was https://www.ath-drivers.eu/atheros-wireless-drivers.html

Comment: That's an unofficial site for Atheros drivers. I wouldn't install anything from there. What is your make/model of laptop?

Comment: Instead of downloading a new driver I found the driver on the computer and updated it.  That resolved the problem.  Device Manager, Network Adapters, (select adapter), update.  The laptop does not have an Ethernet port to plug into the wireless LAN. The laptop is a YOGA 710.